# scala combinator parser to keep original input

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I would like to compose a parser from another parser to have the consumed input as an argument to the ast construction.

Say I have

```
def ingredient = amount ~ nameOfIngredient ^^ {
  case amount ~ name => Ingredient(name, amount)
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to have another parser to construct an element of:

```
case class RecipeRow(orginalText: String, ingredient: Ingredient)
```

So I'm looking for a way to retrieve the original consumed input to the parser in a composition. Maybe something like:

```
def recipeRow = ingredient withConsumedInput ^^ {
  case (amount ~ name, consumed) => RecipeRow(consumed, Ingredient(name, amount))
}
```

I guess the signature in this case would be:

```
def withConsumedInput [U](p: => Parser[U]): Parser[(U, String)]
```

Is there another simple way to get what I want or do I need to write that thing? It feels like it probably is a better way…

Comment: Will this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678228/recursive-parsing-based-on-level-numbers work for you?

Comment: No, I can't see that it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not easy, actually.

Let's start with `Parser`: what can it give us? Well, a `Parser` extends `Input => ParseResult`, so we have to extract the information from either one.

The type `Input` is an alias, on `RegexParsers` anyway, for `scala.util.parsing.input.Reader[Char]`. There's very little there to help us, unless it happens to be a `Reader` of `CharSequence`, in which case we can use `source` and `offset`. Let's use that then.

Now, `ParseResult` has many subclasses, but we are only interested in `Success`, which has a `next: Input` field. Using that, we may try this:

```
def withConsumedInput [U](p: => Parser[U]): Parser[(U, String)] = new Parser[(U, String)] {
  def apply(in: Input) = p(in) match {
    case Success(result, next) =>
      val parsedString = in.source.subSequence(in.offset, next.offset).toString
      Success(result -> parsedString, next)
    case other: NoSuccess      => other
  }
}
```

It will capture any skipped whitespaces, though. You can adapt it to avoid that automatically:

```
def withConsumedInput [U](p: => Parser[U]): Parser[(U, String)] = new Parser[(U, String)] {
  def apply(in: Input) = p(in) match {
    case Success(result, next) =>
      val parsedString = in.source.subSequence(handleWhiteSpace(in.source, in.offset), next.offset).toString
      Success(result -> parsedString, next)
    case other: NoSuccess      => other
  }
}
```