# Scala parser combinators: retrieving the original string that the parser consumed

Tags: parsing, scala, indentation, parser-combinators

So i have a bunch of parsers like this:

```
object MyParser extends RegexParsers{

   override val skipWhitespace = false
   def blockLine  = ((id ~ args) <~ ":") ~ ".*?".r ^^ {
      case (blockID ~ argList) ~ rest => ???
   }


   def args       = (("[" ~> rep1sep(arg, ", ") <~ "]")?) ^^ {
      case Some(argList) =>
           argList.zipWithIndex.map{
              case ((Some(k), v), index) => k -> v
              case ((None, v), index) => "arg" + index -> v
           }
        case None => List()
     }

     def arg        = ((id <~ "=")?) ~ argtext ^^ {
        case Some(name) ~ value => Some(name) -> value.toString()
        case None ~ value=> None -> value
     }

   def argtext    = "[^\\[\\],]+".r
   def id         = "[a-zA-Z]*".r

   ... many other parsers not shown...
```

}

Essentially, I want to re-use the parsers `id` and `args` in `blockLine`, but rather than getting the nested tree of `List()`s and `~`s, I want to get back the original string that was matched. The purpose of this is doing some smart text-preprocessing (using the same parsers that I will use later for the actual parsing) to insert some text in the middle of the line. Something like:

```
def blockLine  = (rawText(id ~ args) <~ ":") ~ ".*?".r ^^ {
   case first ~ rest => first + "{" + rest
}
```

The higher purpose of the preprocessor is to go through and convert indentation-delimited blocks into curly-braces delimited blocks, so I can run the pre-processed file through a normal parser later. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scala combinator parser to keep original input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020852/scala-combinator-parser-to-keep-original-input)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, because, in that question, the @hedefalk wanted both the AST and the string, whereas you just want the string. You can, however, use that solution and discard the AST, or adapt it to return just the string.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: where did you find that? I must have dug through the first two pages of "Scala Parser Combinator" questions on didn't see that. Thanks =)

Comment: Sounds like a job for the `State` monad

Comment: @LiHaoyi I looked at the scala questions about parsing that I had answered most recently -- I answered that question not a week ago! :-)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: could you elaborate? Or point me to somewhere I can dig further? I kind of get that if I wanted to do this in one pass i'll need something to store the state of the current indentation stack, but that's all very fluffy and theoretical and I have no idea how to actually _do_ it

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: I would accept your answer, but I can't accept comments! Should we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: I voted for closing as duplicate, but that didn't get enough votes. You could always answer yourself, with whatever you used in the end.